# Adding many to many relation in SQLAlchemy after Reflection

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, many-to-many

Follwing the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object), I have the following tables defined and populated but no relations have been defined yet.

```
class CountryAssociation(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Country_Region_Mapping'
    country_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('countries.uid'), primary_key=True)
    region_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('regions.uid'), primary_key=True)
    region = relationship('Region', back_populates='country')
    country = relationship('Countries', back_populates='region')
    extra_data = Column(String(50))

class Countries(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'countries'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    countryname = Column('English_short_name', 
           String(255), unique=True, nullable=False) 
    region = relationship('CountryAssociation',
            back_populates='country') 

class Region(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'
    uid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    region = Column(String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
    country = relationship('CountryAssociation', 
        back_populates='region')
```

I now want to create many to many relations between the tables. [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/extensions/automap.html?highlight=base%20automap_base#module-sqlalchemy.ext.automap)

```
Base = automap_base() #reflecting the orm way
engine = create_engine('sqlite:///mydatabse.db')

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

table_countries = Base.classes.countries
table_regions = Base.classes.regions

r = session.query(table_regions).filter(table_regions.region == "Western Europe").first()
c = session.query(table_countries).filter(table_countries.English_short_name == "Germany").first()

c.region.append(r) # this fails with
```

AttributeError: 'countries' object has no attribute 'region'

This however works:

```
c.countryname # Germany
```

I dont get what I am doing wrong here (beginner)...

Comment: Is it possible that reflection does not work with [Association Objects](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object)?

Comment: Have you seen http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/associationproxy.html#simplifying-association-objects?

Comment: `c.countryname` working seems extremely odd and might hint at you having used the `Base = automap_base()` when creating the class definitions originally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've used the [association object pattern](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#association-object) with `extra_data` the automap [relationship detection](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#relationship-detection) will not recognize `Country_Region_Mapping` as a [secondary table of a many to many](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#many-to-many-relationships):

> 2. If the table contains two and exactly two `ForeignKeyConstraint` objects, and all columns within this table are members of these two `ForeignKeyConstraint` objects, the table is assumed to be a “secondary” table, and will **not be mapped directly**.

Put another way: not all columns within `Country_Region_Mapping` are members of the foreign key constraints, so the table is **not a secondary**, so no many to many relationship is created.

Another thing you've overlooked is the [naming scheme](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#overriding-naming-schemes). If you had a working secondary table, then the created relationship would be [named `regions_collection` by default](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/automap.html#sqlalchemy.ext.automap.name_for_collection_relationship) (because of the plural table name).

What does happen is that the many to one / one to many relationships between `regions` and `Country_Region_Mapping`, and `countries` and `Country_Region_Mapping` are created:

```
In [22]: table_countries.country_region_mapping_collection
Out[22]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7f2d600fb258>

In [23]: table_regions.country_region_mapping_collection
Out[23]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7f2d600fbaf0>

In [28]: table_country_region_mapping.countries
Out[28]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7f2d535a2990>

In [29]: table_country_region_mapping.regions
Out[29]: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute at 0x7f2d535a2938>
```

Note that due to plural table naming the scalar relationship attributes on `Country_Region_Mapping` also have plural naming.

With these in mind you'd add a new association like so:

```
In [36]: c.country_region_mapping_collection.append(
    ...:     Base.classes.Country_Region_Mapping(countries=c, regions=r))
```