# SQLAlchemy - query with secondary table with reflected Base

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I work with a pre-existing database and SQLAlchemy. I reflect all tables like

```
Base = automap_base()
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

Then all the classes can be accesed with e.g. `a_table = Base.classes.A`. From documentation I understand, that if a table has only two columns, both foreign keys, then the table

> is assumed to be a “secondary” table, and will not be mapped directly

So the secondary class is not among the classes in the Base and

> The two (or one, for self-referential) external tables to which the
> Table refers to are matched to the classes to which they will be
> mapped, if any. If mapped classes for both sides are located, a
> many-to-many bi-directional relationship() / backref() pair is created
> between the two classes.

But I cannot figure out how to use that in a query. To clarify my scenario, I have tables like shown below and I want to get (depending on A_id) C_ids for B, where B_id is main_B_id in A.

[image]

But whatever query I try it never sees the other table. I tried some workarounds, but I guess there must be some simple way how to achieve that and I just missed some part of the documentation. Any hint would be highly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding many to many relation in SQLAlchemy after Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47738406/adding-many-to-many-relation-in-sqlalchemy-after-reflection)

Comment: I found that post before, but I do not think I use association object. Tried to apply what they suggested, but it did not work well. I found my own solution, but it does not seem to be the correct one even tho it works, so I just wonder now what is the right intended way.